# Can't skip queue items on Chromecast

Tags: ios, google-cast

I integrated `google-cast-sdk` to my app, and when I enqueue some videos, I can't skip next/previous using the controls in the expanded controller.

When I tap the button, nothing happens in the UI or in the Chromecast. The log outputs:

```
-[GCKMediaControlChannel didReceiveTextMessage:]  Received unexpected error: Invalid Request.
-[GCKUIMediaController request:didFailWithError:]  request [incremental number] failed with error Error Domain=com.google.cast.GCKError Code=4 "Invalid request" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid request}
```

To make sure this is not related to my app, I created a blank project/app and only included this Pod: https://github.com/guilhermearaujo/google-cast-bug

**Update**
I tried in both CAF receiver and Style Media receiver. The faulty behaviour is the same in both cases. This is what the Chromecast logs to the debugger:

```
[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Unexpected message type: NEXT
[cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error: INVALID_REQUEST INVALID_COMMAND
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Cast SDK and are you using CAF for the receiver?

Comment: SDK version 4.0.2, and not using CAF, but the default app with custom CSS.

Comment: The CAF receiver has various bug fixes and improvements for queueing; we highly recommend that you migrate to that.

Comment: @LeonNicholls I tried using CAF today, but the same issue happens. This is what the Chromecast log outputs when I tap the Next/Previous button: http://i66.tinypic.com/30jtma1.png

Comment: Please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: @LeonNicholls I already did, almost a month ago: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72220745